# Why can't I use undefined just everywhere?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, constraints, typechecking

I thought I could always put `undefined` in same place where I don't know yet what to put, and the code should compile fine, the error happening at run time only if that `undefined` is actually eveluated.

However, just in doing so I started writing something like

```hs
f = foldl undefined undefined undefined
```

in a file, and GHCi gives this error when I try to load the file

```hs
source.hs:3:7: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘t0’ arising from a use of ‘foldl’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Foldable t0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘t0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Foldable (Either a) -- Defined in ‘Data.Foldable’
        instance Foldable Maybe -- Defined in ‘Data.Foldable’
        instance Foldable ((,) a) -- Defined in ‘Data.Foldable’
        ...plus one other
        ...plus 29 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression: foldl undefined undefined undefined
      In an equation for ‘f’: f = foldl undefined undefined undefined
  |
3 | f = foldl undefined undefined undefined
  |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Which I interpret as "`undefined` does not typecheck here".

What is the rational behind this behavior, and what are the places where I *cannot* use `undefined` as a temporary placeholder?

Comment: It simply does not know *what* foldable it should use, you can write for example `foldl undefined undefined (undefined :: Maybe Int)`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, isn't the same with `undefined + undefined` where it doesn't know what `Num` it should use? I see that `Num` is a typeclass for types, whereas `Foldable` is for type constructors, but still...

Comment: no because for `Num`, there are *defaulting rules* that will default to `Integer`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The interpreter does not know what type for `f` in `foldl :: Foldable f => (a -> b -> a) -> a -> f b -> a` to use, hence the error. This is important since the `f` here decides exactly what implementation for `foldl` it will use. Indeed for a `f ~ Maybe` the implementation can be different than for an `f ~ []`, so depending on the type for `f`, a different `foldl` is used.

If we specify the type, for example with `[Int]`, or `Maybe Char`, this works (well it will raise an error, but this is because the `undefined` will of course not evaluate properly):

```
Prelude> foldl undefined undefined (undefined :: Maybe Char)
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries/base/GHC/Err.hs:78:14 in base:GHC.Err
  undefined, called at <interactive>:1:6 in interactive:Ghci1
Prelude> foldl undefined undefined (undefined :: [Int])
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries/base/GHC/Err.hs:78:14 in base:GHC.Err
  undefined, called at <interactive>:2:6 in interactive:Ghci1
```

For certain type classes like `Num`, there is [*type defaulting* [Wkang's Haskell; blog]](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-04-type-defaulting-in-haskell.html). This uses:

> ```
> default Num Integer
> default Real Integer
> default Enum Integer
> default Integral Integer
> default Fractional Double
> default RealFrac Double
> default Floating Double
> default RealFloat Double
> ```